# Push Notification Android

Tags: android, push-notification, customization

I was unable to locate any specific details about this question, so I'll just shoot it here:
Is Android able to customize a push notification sound / vibration so that it will keep ringing/vibrating the phone until that push is opened (read) ?
If it is possible, could you please give me a hint of how to make it work?

Comment: you are going to drain lots of Battery and your user's might not like it.

Comment: I can understand that, but I'm using this only for emergency, or very important push notifications, leaving user choice to enable it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device can light its LED, play ringtone and so on with configuration of your NoticationManager. They runs just after the push is coming.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(_context)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setTicker("")
            .setAutoCancel(true).setSmallIcon(getSmallIconResId()).setLargeIcon(getLargeIconResId(_context))
            .setContentIntent(null)
            .setContentTitle("").setContentText("");

        builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 }); 
        builder.setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000); 
        builder.setSound(Uri.parse(""));

    return builder;
```

If you wanna keep ringtone, your must play ringtone after the push.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Ringtone.html

Comment: This looks like what I need, but the thing is: How can I set vibrating pattern to be repeated continuously, until the push notification gets clicked. I know that using Vibrator.vibrate the pattern can be repeated with a second int argument, but how to use it with Notifications?

Comment: @DoruAdryan You could vibrate your device just like playing ringtone after push came. http://www.technotalkative.com/android-vibrate-the-phone-programmatically/

Comment: I finally managed to work with it. Thanks for your answer, TeeTraker.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must understand how the PushNotification works. It's a communication channel with client-server. Visually it's a notification like a sms on you're phone. 
However 2 you're question : Yes it's possible. You can set a vibrate,sound and other parameters of you're notification. 
You say how? I don't want to duplicate google search results. So google it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set the vibration and ringtone from the code below. for vibration, you have to add the premission in the manifest.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(_context)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setTicker("")
        .setAutoCancel(true).setSmallIcon(getSmallIconResId());

    builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 }); 
    builder.setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000); 
    builder.setSound(Uri.parse(""));

return builder;
```

Comment: how is this different from the upvoted accepted answer?

Comment: I didnt saw the above answer... I posted of my own.